# Auto Exit Powerpoint Slide Show at the end of run

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Good morning,

I am working on a macro to autorefresh excel links before slideshow, loop through slideshow and then restart over and over again. The issue I am having is the slideshow stops but doesnt exit so the wait timer doesnt have a chance to even kick in.

Can I get a suggestion of how I might fix this?

```
Sub LoopAllSlides()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To 2000

        Dim Endpoint As Single

        Endpoint = Timer + 10
        Do While Timer < Endpoint 'This loop works dont delete
            DoEvents
        Loop



        ActivePresentation.UpdateLinks

        With ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings

        .AdvanceMode = ppSlideShowUseSlideTimings

        .LoopUntilStopped = msoFalse

        .Run

        End With

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this with the Application.Quit function, which will exit out of your current sub. So, something like this:

```
Sub LoopAllSlides()        
    Dim i           As Integer

    For i = 0 To 2000
        Dim Endpoint As Single
        Endpoint = Timer + 10
        Do While Timer < Endpoint        'This loop works dont delete
            DoEvents
        Loop
        ActivePresentation.UpdateLinks
        With ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings
            .AdvanceMode = ppSlideShowUseSlideTimings
            .LoopUntilStopped = msoFalse
            .Run
        End With
    Next i

    'Quit Application Function
    IWishICouldQuitYou

End Sub

Function IWishICouldQuitYou()
    With Application
        For Each w In .Presentations
            w.Save
        Next w
        .Quit
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: I like the Function name lol.

Is there any way I might be able to stop the presentation without exiting the program? 

Im trying to place it in the loop so at the end of all slides being played through, it stops the presentation, then the loop reinitiates the presentation after the wait time. 

I've got limited experience with VBA in powerpoint, I tried running key clicks {ESC} but it just repeatedly exits the presentation without cycling. 

Thanks for the help swolfe2!

Comment: Know what I figured it out. Thank you for the idea!

I just added a second wait loop after the end of the With Statement with the time delay that would allow the powerpoint to run the full duration.